# Data type mismatch error with FilterOn MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm completely stumped. This code was working and is currently working on a different database but just stopped on the one I am working on now. It doesn't make sense why I'm getting a "Data type mismatch in criteria" error when I step through the code all the data that populates is correct. I'm getting the error here: `FilterOn = True`. I don't know how else Debug this code or how to fix it.

Here's the full code for reference:

```
Me.searchlat = TempVars("user").Value
Dim strWhere As String
Dim lngLen As Long

 Const conJetDate = "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#"

 If Not IsNull(Me.searchlat) Then
 strWhere = strWhere & "([workerid] = " & Me.searchlat & " ) AND "
    End If

If Not IsNull(Me.txtStartDate) Then
strWhere = strWhere & "([Dateassigned] >= " & Format(Me.txtStartDate, conJetDate) & ") AND "
    End If

If Not IsNull(Me.txtEndDate) Then
strWhere = strWhere & "([Dateassigned]< " & Format(Me.txtEndDate + 1,   conJetDate) & ") AND "
   End If

 lngLen = Len(strWhere) - 5
 If lngLen <= 0 Then
 MsgBox "No criteria", vbInformation, "Nothing to do."
 Else
 strWhere = Left$(strWhere, lngLen)

 Me.Filter = strWhere
 Me.FilterOn = True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error itself is saying Data Type Mismatch in criteria

In criteria you are checking date and an ID..Date format is fine as per the first look so better put `'` on the id and check as below..

```
Me.searchlat = TempVars("user").Value
Dim strWhere As String
Dim lngLen As Long

 Const conJetDate = "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#"

 If Not IsNull(Me.searchlat) Then
 strWhere =  " ([workerid] = '" & Me.searchlat & "' )  "
    End If

If Not IsNull(Me.txtStartDate) Then
strWhere = strWhere & " AND ([Dateassigned] >= " & Format(Me.txtStartDate, conJetDate) & ")  "
    End If

If Not IsNull(Me.txtEndDate) Then
strWhere = strWhere & " AND ([Dateassigned]< " & Format(Me.txtEndDate + 1,   conJetDate) & ")  "
   End If

 lngLen = Len(strWhere) - 5
 If lngLen <= 0 Then
 MsgBox "No criteria", vbInformation, "Nothing to do."
 END IF

 Me.Filter = strWhere
 Me.FilterOn = True
```

Comment: After 13 hours of re-writing this code you are a life saver!!